# MoveNet Pose Estimation renders inaccurate keypoints

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run the MoveNet Pose Estimation model on a video but for some reason my keypoints are very inaccurate. I assume this does not have anything to do with the predictions itself but with how I calculate the points and paint then using my estimation. However I cannot find where these inaccuracies come from.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='lite-model_movenet_singlepose_lightning_3.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()



def draw_keypoints(frame, keypoints, confidence_threshold):
    y, x, c = frame.shape

    shaped = np.squeeze(np.multiply(keypoints, [y,x,1]))
    
    for kp in shaped:
        ky, kx, kp_conf = kp
        if kp_conf > confidence_threshold:
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(kx), int(ky)), 4, (0,255,0), -1) 


cap = cv2.VideoCapture("pushup-stock-compressed.mp4")
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # Reshape image
    img = frame.copy()
    img = tf.image.resize_with_pad(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0), 192,192)
    input_image = tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    # Setup input and output 
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
    
    # Make predictions 
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], np.array(input_image))
    interpreter.invoke()
    keypoints_with_scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    
    # Rendering 
    draw_keypoints(frame, keypoints_with_scores, 0.4)
    
    cv2.imshow('MoveNet Lightning', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing the `draw_connections` function definition in the code you posted. Also, `draw_keypoints` seems incomplete, it appears to filter keypoints based on a confidence threshold but the keypoints are never actually drawn in that function.

Comment: @stateMachine thank you, I fixed it. I didn't want to include draw_connections to make it simpler to view, but I forgot to remove the draw_connections call

Comment: Is the problem still present? What exactly does tf.image.resize_with_pad do? Probably you have to handle the padding when converting the keypoint positions to your original image resolution.

Comment: @Micka you're right. This is because the method adds padding wich I'm not converting back again. Now I will need to find a good way to account to find this padding but thanks for the help this far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka) in comments you need to take into account that `resize_with_pad` preprocess an image so the returned positions of keypoints will not match the original image.

If you look into tf documentation:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_with_pad

you will find the following description:

```
Resizes an image to a target width and height by keeping the aspect ratio the same without distortion
```

Now we can use the fact that resize+padding could be treated as a affine transformation. Suppose we apply some affine transformation to an image and got keypoints on that preprocessed (resized+padded) image. If we know the matrix of this affine transformation we can find the inverse of it and transform keypoints on the preprocessed image to the locations on the original image by applying founded inverse affine transformation to keypoints.

Let's draw keypoints founded with movenet on the preprocessed image(resize+padded):

[image]

That example contains some incorrect predictions from the network (look at the right leg).

Now apply inverse affine transform to these keypoints
on the original image:

[image]

As we can see the keypoints are drawn at the same positions as on the resized+padded image.

Complete example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(
    model_path="lite-model_movenet_singlepose_lightning_3.tflite"
)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()


def draw_keypoints(frame, keypoints, confidence_threshold):
    for kp in keypoints:
        ky, kx, kp_conf = kp
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(kx), int(ky)), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)


def get_affine_transform_to_fixed_sizes_with_padding(size, new_sizes):
    width, height = new_sizes
    scale = min(height / float(size[1]), width / float(size[0]))
    M = np.float32([[scale, 0, 0], [0, scale, 0]])
    M[0][2] = (width - scale * size[0]) / 2
    M[1][2] = (height - scale * size[1]) / 2
    return M


frame = cv2.imread("gym.png")

# Reshape image
img = frame.copy()
img = tf.image.resize_with_pad(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0), 192, 192)
input_image = tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32)

# Setup input and output
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Make predictions
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]["index"], np.array(input_image))
interpreter.invoke()
keypoints_with_scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]["index"])[0, 0]

img_resized = np.array(input_image).astype(np.uint8)[0]
keypoints_for_resized = keypoints_with_scores.copy()
keypoints_for_resized[:, 0] *= img_resized.shape[1]
keypoints_for_resized[:, 1] *= img_resized.shape[0]
draw_keypoints(img_resized, keypoints_for_resized, 0.4)
cv2.imwrite("image_with_keypoints_resized.png", img_resized)

orig_w, orig_h = frame.shape[:2]
M = get_affine_transform_to_fixed_sizes_with_padding((orig_w, orig_h), (192, 192))
# M has shape 2x3 but we need square matrix when finding an inverse
M = np.vstack((M, [0, 0, 1]))
M_inv = np.linalg.inv(M)[:2]
xy_keypoints = keypoints_with_scores[:, :2] * 192
xy_keypoints = cv2.transform(np.array([xy_keypoints]), M_inv)[0]
keypoints_with_scores = np.hstack((xy_keypoints, keypoints_with_scores[:, 2:]))

# Rendering
draw_keypoints(frame, keypoints_with_scores, 0.4)
cv2.imwrite("image_with_keypoints_original.png", frame)
```